# Redirect domain to new domain keeping the links

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

Okay so I have a website say oldwebsite.com.au and a new website say newwebsite.com.au

I need to redirect and keep all the links therefore traffic from the old site.

So I used this as the redirects (below). Only issue is I have a couple of pages where the url structure has changed and I need to add these to be redirected separately I tried to just add the redirects before the whole site redirects but it didn't seem to work any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#Redirects for individual url that changed. (Not working)
Redirect 301 /about-us.php https://newwebsite.com.au/about-us/
Redirect 301 /category/old-page https://newwebsite.com.au/new-page/


#Redirects for the whole site.
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=old.oldwebsite.com.au
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newwebsite\.com.au
RewriteRule (.*) https://newwebsite.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: the individual url redirects work, if I remove the whole site redirect?...
Note: Im also rot redirecting the subdomain old.oldwebsite.com.au

Comment: Which URL is not getting redirected to new site?

Comment: Redirect 301 /about-us.php https://newwebsite.com.au/about-us/
Redirect 301 /category/old-page https://newwebsite.com.au/new-page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `mod_alias` rules with `mod_rewrite` ones. Have your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# skip subdomain from further rules:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =old.oldwebsite.com.au
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^about-us\.php$ https://newwebsite.com.au/about-us [R=301,L,NE,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/old-page/?$ https://newwebsite.com.au/new-page/ [R=301,L,NE,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newwebsite\.com\.au$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://newwebsite.com.au/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

And don't forget to remove all your `Redirect` rules.

Comment: Thanks for that, all seems to be working now. I will remember that in the future. +1

Comment: I have come into a slight issue with the redirects: old.oldwebsite.com.au sub-domain as it gets redirected the same as oldwebsite.com.au

Comment: I though you wanted to skip redirecting `old.oldwebsite.com.au`. Last rule skips `old.oldwebsite.com.au`.

Comment: Okay so the subdomain 'old' now is the old site, and it needs to function as the old site as it's still in use through the transition of the newwebsite. The redirects for the root of the domain oldwebsite.com.au redirects the urls for the old.oldwebsite.com.au as well. 
How can I make these redirects only apply to the root of the domain oldwebsite.com.au

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but you can try this

following redirect rule:

```
<rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\example.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```